# OleDbConnection connection string Data Source error

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

This is the connection string I am using.

```
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\CULVERT2.DBF;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
```

The error I am receiving is `C:\CULVERT2.DBF' is not a valid path`.

Using C# and .NET 4

Why is it not seeing the file?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misspelled the filename/extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need quotes around the Data Source attribute as well as around the Extended Properties:

```
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"C:\\CULVERT2.DBF\";Extended Properties=\"dBASE IV;\"";
```

Also, you may want to verify that the file is named exactly as you have it, and that you have permissions to the file ;)

UPDATE:

You need to specify only the folder, not the filename as per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/7a3f7bc0-a5c5-45ee-a488-fc262e795ec6.  In your case that would be just `C:\`

Comment: Regrettably, this solution did not work, and I am receiving the same error.

'C:\CULVERT2.DBF' is not a valid path.

Also verified the file name. It is spelled correctly, and all in capital letters.

Comment: Can you also verify the permissions are available to whatever process is trying to open the connection?

Comment: I just ran Visual Studio as administrator with your solution implemented, so it should have the correct permissions, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Is this running as a WinForms application or as a Web site/service?  Web applications will not have the same permissions by default as the user running Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a desktop application that never touches the internet.

Comment: Updated answer with the *real* problem

Comment: That solved my problem there. Pointed it to the folder, and no error has occurred. However, what if there are more than one .DBF files in the folder?

Comment: According to the page noted, each .dbf file represents a *table*, not a database.  The folder acts as the equivalent of the database, and contains multiple tables as individual files.  And here is a more authoritative link that seems to indicate the same - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st4a0s68%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\CULVERT2.DBF;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm still getting the same error when trying to open my connection using this string. 
'C:\CULVERT2.DBF' is not a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by PinnyM it may have something to do with permissions.  Try the solution for Sql Server given in this SO question:

[Unable to open the physical file Operating system error 32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347312/unable-to-open-the-physical-file-operating-system-error-32/6347801#6347801)