# Unable to open the physical file "". Operating system error 32: "32 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the error (below) and am unable to fix, is it possible that someone can provide advise on this. I have a register page which is supposed to save the details on the user to a database. The code is shown below. Thanks

Comment: Without code it's going to be difficult to diagnose the problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to open the physical file Operating system error 32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347312/unable-to-open-the-physical-file-operating-system-error-32)

Comment: Wihtout any **context** it's really hard to say what might be going on. **What** are you trying to do when you get this error??

Comment: Not as difficult as you might think?  I used the 'Google' debggging tool to find out that Error 32 is ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".  You got a zombie database in there?

Comment: @beny23 Hi all, edited above with code, help appreciated

Comment: OK - you've dumped a pile of code on us - now tell us **WHERE** in that code this error occurs, please.....

Comment: And if you remove the try..catch block, in what line does the error occur?

Comment: @MrLister No error it displays the message "Record was successfully added!" however there is no data in the database

Comment: Wait, what? You didn't remove all the content of `ExecuteInsert`, did you?

Comment: @MrLister no just the try and catch like u stated

Comment: @MrLister did you manage to look at my last comment?

Answer (score 1):

Check that GetConnectionString is returning what you want.

note: Details on what line is throwing the exception would be more helpful than the catch statement when indicating where the error is occurring

Comment: how do I do this? sorry new to all this

Comment: string connstr = GetConnectionString(); as the first line of ExecuteInsert and examine in debugger (put breakpoint on line right after you add this), or output to console

Comment: hi managed to fix the error, there was an issue with my connection string, I made the amendment and now it works appropriately. Thanks

Comment: @user1300580 if msam answer helped you click the little green arrow below the up vote number. that way they will receive credit for their contribution