# asp.net cannot open database login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm using the following to retrieve data from a database but the `SqlConnection` won't open. It throws an error at `scon.Open()`. I'm sure it's elementary but I can't work it out.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = populate.mdf; Integrated Security = true; Initial Catalog = populate");   

    StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder(); 

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            scmd.Connection = scon;
            scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            scmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM populate";

            scon.Open();

            SqlDataReader articleReader = scmd.ExecuteReader();

            htmlString.Append("'Populate page:'");                

            if (articleReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (articleReader.Read())
                {
                    htmlString.Append(articleReader["dateTime"]);
                    htmlString.Append(articleReader["firstName"]);
                    htmlString.Append(articleReader["lastName"]);
                    htmlString.Append(articleReader["address"]);
                    htmlString.Append(articleReader["details"]);
                }

                populatePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlString.ToString() });
                articleReader.Close();
                articleReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx as one of my references. I'm also using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express if these information are of any help.

Here's part of the error message:

> SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "populate" requested
>   by the login. The login failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that the user that the website is running under doesn't have access to the database.  Are you using IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: @BrendanGreen: IIS Express. When  I comment out the code above, my GridView displays the same data through SqlDataSource.

Comment: I'm still uncertain: is your **database** called `populate`, and the table you're dealing with inside that database is **also** called `populate` ?? Seems odd..... what **databases** do you see if you connect to your `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance with Management Studio? In SQL Server, a **database** contains **multiple** tables - so those are typically *not* called the same!

Comment: @marc_s: That's right, the db is populate.mdf and the table is also named 'populate'. My project will end up with several databases if not hundreds so for now it's a matter of testing ways to name everything methodically. In the Management Studio only the .dbo files are showing but I now know how to get the .mdf files. Why do you ask?

Comment: You could try to **attach** the `populate.mdf` to your server - use Object Explorer -> Databases -> Attach to attach the `.mdf` - you cannot just "open" it, you need to use the **Attach** method. Once it's attached to the server - ***then*** (and only then) you should be able to connect to it using that connection string you've been trying

Comment: @marc_s: Strange, I've attached it to the Management Studio already as I have mentioned above but it still won't open, with the same error to the original one. I think there's been enough time I've spent on this with little progress so I will call in a expert to do it for me. It's been interesting anyway. For extra information, if I comment out this code, I get the same data that I want displayed in GridView using SqlDataSource but don't worry too much about it now. I'll call in a consultant programmer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @marc_s: All the code was correct. The database just needed connecting in the Management Studio. I had to manually refresh the database when attached to MS otherwise it still threw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. All the connection string and other code was correct. The database just needed connecting to the Management Studio with some extra attention.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse, if you want to use .mdf file as a database, you should use the following connection string containing **AttacheDbFileName**.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and I get this error which again points directly to the database: <<<SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to open the physical file "  [my directory]\App_Data\populate.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)">>>

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347312/unable-to-open-the-physical-file-operating-system-error-32 for a try

Comment: Thanks, great effort. I tried a lot of the different tactics but it didn't work. One that I wasn't able to try was to reset the properties|security|Authenticate Users|Edit|Allow|Full Control|OK. I don't seem to have the right properties features.